# Expression Expected in registerReceiver - AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, android-broadcastreceiver

I am trying to auto read message into EditText using SMS Broadcast Receiver. While I am registering BroadcastReceiver error occured of **"Expression Expected"**

```
IntentFilter smsFilter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
this.registerReceiver(SMSReceiver, smsFilter); //Expression Expected error occurred here
```

**SOLVED :**

I have just added new  `this.registerReceiver(new SMSReceiver(), smsFilter);` instead of  `this.registerReceiver(SMSReceiver, smsFilter);`

I hope this might help you.

Comment: I think first parameter should be `new SMSReceiver()` instead of class name `SMSReceiver`

Comment: Thanks a tons.. It works fine now.. Cheers @ρяσѕρєя K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter should be `new SMSReceiver()` instead of class name `SMSReceiver` as mentioned in a comment by  @ρяσѕρєя K.

I would rather recommend to instantiate  it in your `onCreate()` and then use it in `registerReceiver()` and `unregisterReceiver()`

```
// in onCreate or globally
SMSReceiver smsReceiver= new SMSReceiver();  
...

// and then in onResume  
IntentFilter smsFilter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
registerReceiver(smsReceiver, smsFilter);
....

// and in pause
unregisterReceiver(smsReceiver);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have u add the following code in manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

If not then add this.

Add hope the ***SMSReceiver*** is the ***BroadcastReceiver's*** instance. If not then create the instance of BroadcastReceiver

Comment: I have already added all required permissions, It was just a syntax error and resolved. Thanks anyway. Cheers